# Select a column based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

```
select 
claim_id,
case when flex_field1_label = 'Member ID' then flex_field1_value
when flex_field2_label = 'Member ID' then flex_field2_value
when flex_field3_label = 'Member ID' then flex_field3_value
when flex_field4_label = 'Member ID' then flex_field4_value
when flex_field5_label = 'Member ID' then flex_field5_value end as "Member ID"
from claim_flexfields
```

[image: Dbeaver]

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficiently?" Shorter SQL statement? Less redundancy in the SQL statement? More flexibility in modifying the code for different cases? Shorter execution time? Something else?

Comment: Less redundancy and More flexibility, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Shorter SQL would be:

```
    SELECT
        claim_id,
        CASE WHEN 'Member ID' IN (flex_field1_label, flex_field2_label,
        flex_field3_label, flex_field4_label, flex_field5_label) THEN 'Member ID'
        END AS "Member ID"
    FROM
        claim_flexfields;
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. OP is selecting one of `flex_fieldX_value` based on which of the corresponding `flex_fieldX_label` values is "Member ID". On the other hand, your code is *always* selecting "Member ID" as the column value.

Comment: `when flex_fieldX_label = 'Member ID'` in the select statement shows that the value of `flex_fieldX_value` is 'Member ID'.

Comment: I need flex_fieldX_value when flex_fieldX_label = 'Member ID'